# How to target a Bootstrap modal using Typeahead JS in an Angular controller

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js

Im using Bootstrap, typeahead JS and angular. I cant target the Bootstrap modal from the typeahead template in the angular controller. It doesnt recognize the angular expression in the footer which has to target the modal in the HTML. This probably has to do with the template that doesnt recognize the angular expressions.

So, I would like to target the BS modal from the footer in the template. Is there a proper solution to make this work?

See my code:

```
    <div id="something{{some.id}}" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm"    tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel"
         aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                   header here...
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    content here...
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                   footer here...
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>    



// code in angular controller:

    events.initialize();
    $scope.eventsDataset = {
        name: 'events',
        displayKey: 'title',
        source: events.ttAdapter(),
        templates: {
            empty: 'this is empty',
            suggestion: Handlebars.compile ('<p>{{title}}</p>'),
            footer: '<p class="footer" data-toggle="modal" data-target= "#something{{some.id}}">you can click here..</p>'
        }
    };
    $scope.exampleOptions = {
        highlight: true
    };`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

> Remove the `#` in the `id` attribute for your modal window div.

As a side node, for the footer give a structure like below instead of a string. It will be more readable and maintainable in my opinion.

```
footer: function() {
  return $('<p></p>')
    .addClass('footer')
    .attr('data-toggle', 'modal')
    .attr('data-target', '#something1')
    .html('click me');
}
```

Here is a **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pegp21r7/23/)** showing the same

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the your effort! But the # in id attribute was a spelling error. I have edited in the above.  Sorry for that... The id has to be created dynamically with use of angular. The expression used {{some.id}} refers to an id in a json file. The problem is that there is a conflict between angular en jquery..
This is what I get in the console: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #something{{some.id}}. It should say  #something1, #something2, #something3 etc. Any ideas?